# Where are the Brawl stats

Tags: overwatch

Where are the brawl stats stored. How Can I view them? I've noticed that in the career profile section, there are three areas of stats that I can view, Quick play, Competitive and AI games. I'm not sure what competitive is, but I've got stats for quick play and AI games, my competative stats are all blank.

While playing in the brawl I think that I'm getting career best for things that I've already done in quick play, something that I've noticed when switching between ai games and quickplay, this leads me to believe that the brawl stats are seperate, is this true?

Where can I view brawl stats?

Comment: Also competitive was a thing during beta and is coming back later this year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to watch the stats you have acquired during brawl.

Comment: Not only is there no way to check your brawl stats- they appear to not be stored anywhere either. I've noticed a career best of 81 healing in one session when I had career best 1022 in a previous game session (both times I was Roadhog for the full duration of the map, no deaths).

Comment: @KizTrap I was watching those stats pretty closely, and my conclusion was that the career best was per hero *per map*.

Comment: @DCShannon AFAIK brawl stats will be shown to you after every match, but will not be saved at all, because I have all carreer bests every time.

Comment: @Lunaetic That's certainly possible. I haven't taken the time to write down stats and science it.

Answer (score 4):

As, [Riley's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270147/140266) plainly states, there is currently no way to view your stats from brawls. A quick google search will show that there are plenty of people asking for this feature and so far, [Blizzard has been pretty good about listening to the players](http://kotaku.com/blizzard-removing-overwatch-butt-pose-after-fan-complai-1767613551), so this may be a feature that we see some day.

To offer a potential explanation as to why this feature was not included, there have been [14 brawls announced so far](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Weekly_Brawl) and potentially more to come. In order to show stats for brawls I see a couple options for presenting the data, none of which are very good:

1. Individual stat sheets for each brawl

This could get bulky quick if they add many more brawls over time and for the game types like We're All Soldiers Now, the page would be very bare and uninteresting given how they currently show stats, for example, you would only have one bar and then a big drop-down like the professionally edited image below

[image]
[Original image without my additions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcY63.jpg)

Either that or you need a different screen layout just for brawls, which is not good from a UX perspective.

2. One nonsensical page that wouldn't tell you very much.

For example, you would see stats for McCree from High Noon (headshots only) and The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly (not too different from public quick play) and Arcade (more health, short cooldowns, faster ult charge and short respawns). This would become more convoluted if they add more brawls, like types where they drastically increase/decrease damage or healing.